# NGINX multiple server blocks - 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I'm trying to setup multiple servers using `Nginx` and `Docker`. For now, I want to make it work locally but I'll export this into to use it in a website. My `nginx.conf` is:

```
worker_processes 1;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {
    client_max_body_size 2048M;
    sendfile on;

    upstream docker-phpmyadmin {
        server phpmyadmin;
    }
    upstream docker-wordpress {
        server wordpress;
    }
    upstream docker-api {
        server api;
    }
    upstream docker-frontend {
        server frontend;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com;
        location / {
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_pass http://docker-frontend;
        }
    }
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name api.example.com;
        location / {
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_pass http://docker-api;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name db.example.com;
        location / {
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_pass http://docker-phpmyadmin;
        }
    }
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name admin.example.com;
        location / {
            proxy_read_timeout 3600;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_pass http://docker-wordpress;
        }
    }
}
```

I've added these entries to my `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1 example.com
127.0.0.1 db.example.com
127.0.0.1 api.example.com
127.0.0.1 admin.example.com
```

My `docker-compose.yml` contains:

```
  nginx:
    build: ./backend/nginx
    links:
      - wordpress
      - phpmyadmin
      - frontend
    ports: 
      - ${NGINX_EXTERNAL_PORT}:80
    volumes:
      - "./backend/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf"
```

So, locally, `NGINX_EXTERNAL_PORT` is set to 5000. I can access to `db.example.com:5000` and to `admin.example.com:5000`, but when I try to access to my main page `example.com:5000` I get:

```
nginx_1       | 2019/09/18 21:26:52 [error] 6#6: *8 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.18.0.1, server: example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.18.0.7:80/", host: "example.com:5000"
nginx_1       | 172.18.0.1 - - [18/Sep/2019:21:26:52 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 559 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36"
```

Am I missing something on my configuration for that server block? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be because the application that was in `example.com` was not exposing any port, so after including `EXPOSE 3000` to the `Dockerfile` and changing the upstream to

```
upstream docker-frontend{
    server frontend:3000;
}
```

Works!